# Is there anyway i can give id to each recycler view which i created dynamically?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a integer counter which sets the number of recycler view to be created. Is there a way i can associate an id with each of the recycler view created?

Comment: Why you need this?

Comment: @ShayanPourvatan I get the integer counter from a server method, according to which i have to create horizontal recycler views holding informations of items such as books, toys etc but i need an id so that i can detect which recycler view the user is using.

Comment: Maybe create a map relating `RecyclerView` references to an Id?

`Map<RecyclerView, String> ids = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 0):

put one textview in your recycler view  and make it as visibility gone and set value to that textview in adapter. If you want that value then retrieve and use as you need.

Answer (score 0):

If by “id” you refer to a simple indexing of your items than you can use `ParrentView.getChildAt(i)`, where ParrentView is a container for your RecyclerViews.

If you need R.id for the specific member of your RecyclerViews than you can target that element by calling `.findViewById()` on View child.